# Angular Material : Change background color of a dialog window

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

I don't know why but my dialog is **black** (#424242) instead of **white** (by default) and this is the same for my datatable.

[image: Screenshot of a dialog overlaid on top of a table]

Overwriting the **CSS** does not work.
Does anyone know how to change the **background-color** by default or just change the **color**?

Comment: This is probably because you're using the prebuilt `purple-green.css` theme, based on the primary and accent colours that your dialog is using. This prebuilt theme is intentionally a dark theme. If you're not intending to use this theme, there are still 2 other light themes that you can choose from: `indigo-pink.css` or `deeppurple-amber.css`. Check out the theming guide for more info: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Comment: @Edric That's right, I have changed `purple-green` by `indigo-pink` and it solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it with css then there are 2 ways.

1. Using `component.css` file

Write `::ng-deep <selector>` in your `component.css` file to overwriting the css applied by material.

2. Using `style.css` file

if you write your css in `style.css` that exists in root folder of angular project then you dont have to add `::ng-deep` in front of your selectors.

Comment: Indeed, `::ng-deep` works fine and it overwrites the CSS. Thanks.

Comment: You should also look into @Edric's comment. That might be the root of your problems.

Comment: You both helped me! @Edric for my initial problem and you for overwrite the CSS. :o)

Comment: @Pran Kumar Sarkar Can you create a sample stackblitz example and share with us.

Comment: I found the issue with my code. I was trying to set background color with `:host ::ng-deep selector` but I saw that :host doesn't seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 4):

F12 Debug on Browser, you will see **mat-dialog-container** tag doesn't belong to **app-root**.
so you have to change CSS of **mat-dialog-container** globally in ***styles.scss*** file:

```
mat-dialog-container {
   background-color: greenyellow !important;
}
```

another way is changing Material theme globally in **styles.scss**.

if you want to change background color different for dialogs, set background color of  = transparency. then set background color for dialog component.

styles.scss:

```
mat-dialog-container {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: !important change all dialogs. Not only that one.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a custom panelClass in your matDialogConfig Object.

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
  panelClass: 'my-css-class'
});
```

Now put your class in any global CSS File e.g. in styles.css. global scoped to be applied on that CSS File.

```
.my-css-class .mat-dialog-container{
  /* add your styles */
}
```

Comment: Do you need to include ".mat-dialog-container" part in css? Also is this upto date with the latest update? I believe they add 'mat-mdc' to the front of many class names, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I want to make transparent material dialog background. Unfortunately already given answers didn't work. But this works perfectly.

override `mdc-dialog__surface` class,

```
.mdc-dialog__surface {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In angular 15+ , if you prefer just changing the background in the component where the dialog is called, you can override the background by this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-dialog-container {
  --mdc-dialog-container-color: #c9e4d9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to avoid *::ng-deep* as it is deprecated.

Keep a global stylesheet. If it's splitted into multiple stylesheets make sure your stylesheet where you override material component themes comes in a later order.

This will result in overriding material classes otherwise you will still see color from the material dark background. I did this silly mistake of imports.

I added this in one of my root level scss file for dialogue. ($grey is my own version)

```
mat-dialog-container {
   background: $grey !important;
}
```

NOTE:

> '!important'

is important here :)

Answer (score 1):

**100% working**
In your component.ts file

```
const dialogCompRef = this.dialog.open(YourDialogComponent,{
  width:'700px',
  height:'550px',
  panelClass: 'bg-color' // Add your custom panel class
});
```

**add this into styles.scss**

```
   .bg-color .mat-dialog-container{
         background-color: red;
       }
```